Open files are closed when Android Studio goes to the background
In android studio, in only one of my projects, when I go to another screen and return to android studio, the open files are closed and I cannot see the contents of the files.
This is the case only in one of my projects, there is no such problem in my other projects.
I added a video below, you can see the problem clearly.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KB3eNc9D52I

The video sharing platform you used requires registration; you will lose a lot of viewers that way. Can you change the video to public, or share it on a platform which doesn't require us to give them our email address (with no guarantees that they won't sell it to the spammers in their next breath)?

@tripleee Thanks, I replaced it with youtube.
